# SonarQube publish quality gate result takes far too long

Tags: .net-core, sonarqube, azure-devops

Publishing Quality Gate results take way too long. Right now, when I publish using the respective Azure DevOps task, I have to wait for at least 18min until the process finished. The project doesn't have a huge codebase (only 45k lines of code) and as far as I can see, the process itself doesn't load our Azure-based database as well. What could be the issue? Are there any ways of improving QG publishing performance?

Answer (score 3):

The *Publish Quality Gate* step polls the SonarQube server until the background processing on the server has completed, and then posts the success/failure result to the Azure DevOps build summary page.

If you can live without the SQ summary on the build summary page then you can just disable the *Publish Quality Gate* step.

To investigate why the step is taking so long you need to look at your SonarQube server. The docs on [Background Tasks](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/background-tasks/) describe how to look at the background processing to see how long each task is taking. There are also perf suggestions on the [Hardware Recommendations](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/hardware-recommendations/) and [Benchmark](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/benchmark/) pages. If you are using the Enterprise edition you can increase the number of [compute engine workers](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/compute-engine-performance/).

Comment: Not too much use of this documentation. It seems the only way is to increase the number of workers that is only possible in EE... which is ridiculous, considering its price. Are there any specific recommendations for Windows platforms?